# Rspec+capybara request specs: testing form submit with invisible button: best way to make button invisible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have a one-textfield form on my app. I don't want a visible submit button (users have to hit 'enter' to submit). I understand you still want the button there for accessibility, so I move it offscreen.

I'm testing with Capybara. When I `click_on my-button`, it gives me this error:

```
Failure/Error: click_on "gimme-your-cc"
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError:
   Element cannot be scrolled into view:[object HTMLInputElement]
```

That particular spec is done within a `js: true` block so it uses webdriver and firefox.

Is there a good way to test submitting that button? Making it the button `display:hidden` didn't work either and I think that solution isn't very accessible anyway.

Comment: `page.execute_script("$('#submit_id').click();")`

Comment: good answer, add it and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good work around would be to use javascript:

```
page.execute_script("$('#submit_id').click();")
```

Comment: This works great. `sleep(1)` may be required after that call if the following tests don't seem to work.

Comment: ^ You can use `wait_until` to avoid using sleep.

Comment: wait_until has been deprecated in in Capybara 2.0.  The execute_script solution worked for me too!

Comment: It submits the form with format JS.
How do I submit with format HTML??